# What kind of graph is this? Hamiltonian by association?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, hamiltonian-path

Here is an example of a connected cycle using the edges:
$ABC-BCD-BCE-CDE-BDE-ABE-ACE-ADE-ACD$

Here $ABC$ shares $BC$ with $BCD$, $BCD$ shares $BC$ with $BCE$, ... , $ACD$ shares $AC$ with $ABC$. These shared edges converted to vertices themselves form a Hamiltonian cycle and path by association, but these edges are not directed so they can't be drawn in a path. A hamiltonian path is a path which visits each vertex only once.

These can form hamiltonian paths and cycles as subsets, but the whole set does not give a Hamiltonian path. I'm wondering if there's a name for a graph like this?

Comment: See [Johnson graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_graph) and [generalized Kneser graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph).

Answer (score 1):

You could think of this as some very complicated and hard-to-define object in a graph where $A,B,C,D,E$ are vertices and $AB, AC, AD, \dots, CE, DE$ are edges. But that's not very enlightening.

Instead, you could take your graph to have $$ABC, ABD, ABE, ACD, ACE, ADE, BCD, BCE, BDE, CDE$$ as its vertices, with an edge between two triples that have two letters in common. This graph happens to be isomorphic to the complement of the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph).

If you do this, then your sequence is just an ordinary Hamiltonian cycle in this graph.